# Video becomes choppy when the order in the hstack filter is changed

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a FFmpeg command wherein I am merging 2 videos side by side using hstack filter. When I place first video on the right hand side and second video on the left hand side, the final merged video is perfect in quality and plays smoothly.

However, when I swap the order in hstack filter, the final video is very choppy.

Can someone please let me know the issue in this command? Many thanks in advance.

Also, the file size of the non working file is almost double than that of working file. Can you explain why?

Here is the working command:

```
ffmpeg -i 1_a.opus -i 2_a.opus -itsoffset 0.024 -i 1_v.mp4 -itsoffset 0.113 -i 2_v.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=15646|15646[a1]; [0:a][a1]amix; [3:v]trim=0:15.646,geq=0:128:128[silence]; [3:v]fifo[3v]; [silence][3v]concat[3_v_silence]; [3_v_silence][2:v]hstack" -preset ultrafast -y n_m_bars_try2.mp4
```

output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.0.2-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, ogg, from '1_a.opus':
  Duration: 00:01:03.82, start: -0.020000, bitrate: 37 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
Input #1, ogg, from '2_a.opus':
  Duration: 00:00:52.40, start: -0.020000, bitrate: 44 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1_v.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:01:03.85, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2644 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 2633 kb/s, 333 fps, 333 tbr, 10656 tbn, 666 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2_v.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:00:52.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 861 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 860 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (opus) -> amix:input0
  Stream #1:0 (opus) -> adelay
  Stream #2:0 (h264) -> hstack:input1
  Stream #3:0 (h264) -> trim
  Stream #3:0 (h264) -> fifo
  amix -> Stream #0:0 (aac)
  hstack -> Stream #0:1 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x528d600] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x528d600] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 Cache64 SlowShuffle
[libx264 @ 0x528d600] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x528d600] 264 - core 155 r2901 7d0ff22 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
Output #0, mp4, to 'navid_mayank_bars_try2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 aac
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 8:3], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame= 1704 fps= 42 q=-1.0 Lsize=   14440kB time=00:01:08.12 bitrate=1736.5kbits/s dup=3 drop=21229 speed=1.69x    
video:13448kB audio:953kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.269503%
[aac @ 0x52b8680] Qavg: 22255.799
[libx264 @ 0x528d600] frame I:7     Avg QP:16.29  size: 46284
[libx264 @ 0x528d600] frame P:1697  Avg QP:18.36  size:  7924
[libx264 @ 0x528d600] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x528d600] mb P  I16..4:  1.8%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 31.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:67.2%
[libx264 @ 0x528d600] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 29.9% 59.3% 17.5% inter: 13.4% 24.6% 0.8%
[libx264 @ 0x528d600] i16 v,h,dc,p: 36% 29% 18% 17%
[libx264 @ 0x528d600] i8c dc,h,v,p: 42% 25% 21% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x528d600] kb/s:1616.23
```

Non working command:

```
ffmpeg -i 1_a.opus -i 2_a.opus -itsoffset 0.024 -i 1_v.mp4 -itsoffset 0.113 -i 2_v.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=15646|15646[a1]; [0:a][a1]amix; [3:v]trim=0:15.646,geq=0:128:128[silence]; [3:v]fifo[3v]; [silence][3v]concat[3_v_silence]; [2:v][3_v_silence]hstack" -preset ultrafast -y m_n_bars_try2.mp4
```

output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.0.2-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, ogg, from '1_a.opus':
  Duration: 00:01:03.82, start: -0.020000, bitrate: 37 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
Input #1, ogg, from '2_a.opus':
  Duration: 00:00:52.40, start: -0.020000, bitrate: 44 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1_v.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:01:03.85, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2644 kb/s
    Stream #2:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 2633 kb/s, 333 fps, 333 tbr, 10656 tbn, 666 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Input #3, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2_v.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
  Duration: 00:00:52.32, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 861 kb/s
    Stream #3:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 860 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (opus) -> amix:input0
  Stream #1:0 (opus) -> adelay
  Stream #2:0 (h264) -> hstack:input0
  Stream #3:0 (h264) -> trim
  Stream #3:0 (h264) -> fifo
  amix -> Stream #0:0 (aac)
  hstack -> Stream #0:1 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x6d21600] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x6d21600] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 Cache64 SlowShuffle
[libx264 @ 0x6d21600] profile Constrained Baseline, level 5.1
[libx264 @ 0x6d21600] 264 - core 155 r2901 7d0ff22 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=0 ref=1 deblock=0:0:0 analyse=0:0 me=dia subme=0 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=0 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc=crf mbtree=0 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=0
Output #0, mp4, to 'mayank_navid_bars_try2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 aac
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 8:3], q=-1--1, 333 fps, 10656 tbn, 333 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Past duration 0.999992 too large
    Last message repeated 12 times
More than 1000 frames duplicated   33280kB time=00:01:08.03 bitrate=4007.4kbits/s dup=982 drop=1590 speed=0.536x    
frame=22679 fps=177 q=-1.0 Lsize=   33892kB time=00:01:08.10 bitrate=4076.9kbits/s dup=1339 drop=1590 speed=0.531x    
video:32804kB audio:953kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.401324%
[aac @ 0x6d4c680] Qavg: 22255.799
[libx264 @ 0x6d21600] frame I:91    Avg QP:15.31  size: 51639
[libx264 @ 0x6d21600] frame P:22588 Avg QP:18.24  size:  1279
[libx264 @ 0x6d21600] mb I  I16..4: 100.0%  0.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x6d21600] mb P  I16..4:  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4: 13.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:86.8%
[libx264 @ 0x6d21600] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 44.9% 54.0% 29.9% inter: 2.0% 10.9% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x6d21600] i16 v,h,dc,p: 45% 24% 13% 18%
[libx264 @ 0x6d21600] i8c dc,h,v,p: 51% 20% 18% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x6d21600] kb/s:3945.79
```

Answer (score 1):

One of your videos is 333 fps and the other is 25.  The order in which you apply them affects the frame rate of the output file.  25 is much easier to output than 333.  Try adding '-r pal' just before declaring your output file.